# [MongoDB]How to retrieve values from an array in java mongo

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

i'm trying to retrieve and access to an array

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59325acd2d9d3069cf439512"),
"name" : "harry"
 "fruits" : [ "apple", "orange" ]
 }
```

so i manage to retrieve the whole document but i want to access to a specific value in my array (let's say 'apple')

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "harry"));

DBCursor results = coll.find(query);

while (results.hasNext()) { `

    results.next().get("fruits");


}
```

i looked for some way to cast that object as an array but didn't succeed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: cast `results.next().get("fruits");` into a [BasicDBList](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.9.3/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html)  which is basically a `List`

Comment: thank you Ori Dar.